# Converting a string into an array of fixed length

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string that I want to convert into an array of 6 elements.

```
 $x=Address : "MK/LK G8, 2ND FLR, MALAL VISO INFO 19-Aug-15 Acct Number :   _254566003 etc...
```

IF I want an array

```
$parts[0]=MK/LKG......Length should be 6 (whitespace wont consider)
$parts[1]=82NDFLRLength should be 6
$parts[2]=etc.....
```

Comment: i recommend studying about arrays http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

Comment: And I recommend finding another learning source other than [w3fools](http://w3fools.com)

Answer (score 0):

try this to split strings to array

```
$str = "MK/LK G8, 2ND FLR, MALAL VISO INFO 19-Aug-15 Acct Number : _254566003 etc..."
$arr = str_split($str, 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `str_split` along with the `preg_replace` as

```
$x="MK/LK G8, 2ND FLR, MALAL VISO INFO 19-Aug-15 Acct Number : _254566003 etc..";
$res = str_split(preg_replace('/\s/','',$x),6);
print_r($res);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => MK/LKG
    [1] => 8,2NDF
    [2] => LR,MAL
    [3] => ALVISO
    [4] => INFO19
    [5] => -Aug-1
    [6] => 5AcctN
    [7] => umber:
    [8] => _25456
    [9] => 6003et
    [10] => c..
)
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/419503)